# How to make various list using random.sample()?

Tags: python, list, loops

in this list

```
AIB13seoul= ['김예나','김혜관','노주연','박진수','박희선','양건희','양세비',
             '이예지','전형준','정승기','sangwon','이지현','김강호','김슬기',
             '김용석','김재성','방준원','한유성','한현구','강병우']
```

I want to make 3 other random lists called `a`, `b`, and `c` without duplicates, using loop.
I'm not used to utilizing loops, so this is how I tried originally:

```
import random
a = random.sample(AIB13seoul, 7)
list(a)
removed=list(set(AIB13seoul) - set(a))
b = random.sample(removed, 7)
removed1=list(set(removed) - set(b))
c = random.sample(removed1, 6)
```

And this is the file I'm using: [off-site file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13thBDmHfjRM7rduhEepu-PrNX3G2flxu?hl=ko#scrollTo=TrdcfvpN3q31)

I tried this:

```
a=[]
for x in AIB13seoul:
    select=random.sample(AIB13seoul,7)
    a.append(select)

print(a)
```

but it didn't work .

Comment: Were all of these quotation marks in the original code?

Comment: Couldn't you shuffle the original list, and just take 3 adjacent slices of that?

Comment: What is the problem with the first code sample? The second code sample won't work because parts of code are strings only.

Comment: Show code, input, output, errors, etc. as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. Your post is missing a clear description of the problem (what actually happened when you ran the code, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen? "didn't work" is not helpful), and a clear, specific  question ("plz help me" is not a question at all, and the title does not focus on the problem).

Comment: The results you're getting look fine to me — what is wrong with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a fairly flexible implementation with `numpy` and `random`:

```python
import random as rand 
import numpy as np


def split(list, subdivisions):

    l = rand.sample(list, len(list))
    splits = [int(len(l) * split) for split in np.linspace(0, 1, subdivisions + 1)]
    return [ l[splits[i] : splits[i+1]] for i in range(len(splits) - 1)]

split(AIB13seoul, 3)
```

Which results in:

```python
> [['한현구', '김강호', '방준원', '양세비', '박희선', '한유성'],
  ['김재성', '김혜관', '이지현', '양건희', '김슬기', '박진수', '정승기'],
  ['김용석', '노주연', '강병우', '이예지', 'sangwon', '전형준', '김예나']]
```